# Apache AGE - Creating Materialized View Error

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I wanted to create a materialized view from a label table and then create indexes on it. However, when I type the query to create this view, postgres pops an error.

Here is the query that I type to return all the vertices containing the "Book" label :

```sql
demo=# SELECT * FROM cypher ('demo', $$
demo$# MATCH (v:Book)
demo$# RETURN v
demo$# $$) as (vertex agtype);
                                                                vertex
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": 1125899906842625, "label": "Book", "properties": {"title": "The Hobbit"}}::vertex
 {"id": 1125899906842626, "label": "Book", "properties": {"title": "SPQR: A History of Ancient Rome", "author": "Mary Beard"}}::vertex
(2 rows)
```

Here is the way that I'm creating the materialized view :

```sql
demo=# CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW book_view AS SELECT * FROM cypher ('demo', $$
MATCH (v:Book)
RETURN v.author, v.title
$$) as (author agtype, title agtype);

ERROR:  unhandled cypher(cstring) function call
DETAIL:  demo
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can't call a function like `cypher` to create a view. Therefore, you should try using a SQL SELECT statement like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW book_view AS 
    SELECT properties->'author' AS author,
           properties->'title' AS title 
    FROM demo."Book";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a workaround by first creating a temporary table and populating it with the results of your Cypher query. Then, create a materialized view using the data from the temporary table. Use the following steps:

- Create a temporary table to store the results of your Cypher query
- Create the materialized view using the data from the temporary table
- Optionally, create indexes on the materialized view